# Most efficient conditional statement for multiple options?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm new to c# and trying to make a conditional statement where I'm checking what option my script should select on a webpage. Right now I'm doing it like this where I have made individual bool statements for each options and I have a long else if statement checking each of them.

```
bool PersonalPolicy = true;
bool FarmOwnersPolicy = true;

if (PersonalPolicy)
{
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_ctl_WorkflowManager_Quote_Farm_ctl_Farm_Basic_Policy_Info_radioListCommOrPersonal_0")).Click();
}
else
{
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_ctl_WorkflowManager_Quote_Farm_ctl_Farm_Basic_Policy_Info_radioListCommOrPersonal_1")).Click();
}
if (FarmOwnersPolicy)
{
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_ctl_WorkflowManager_Quote_Farm_ctl_Farm_Basic_Policy_Info_rdoPolicyType_0")).Click();
}
else if (SelectoMaticPolicy)
{
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_ctl_WorkflowManager_Quote_Farm_ctl_Farm_Basic_Policy_Info_rdoPolicyType_1")).Click();
}
else
{
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("cphMain_ctl_WorkflowManager_Quote_Farm_ctl_Farm_Basic_Policy_Info_rdoPolicyType_2")).Click();
}
```

The problem is for some things I want to check there are a ton of options I don't want to make a million bool statements and have really long else if statements. Is there an easier way to format this ?

Comment: Define your elements as per POM, e.g. `[FindsBy(How = How.ID, Using = "cphMain_BLAHBLAHBLAHType_1")]
        public IWebElement RandomClickableElement;`. Then call it by `RandomClickableElement.Click();`

Comment: I don't know if this could be rewritten not to use so many conditions, but I think you could minimise the code you need to write by extracting the code inside the if else statements in a separate method which does driver.find... and appends a parameter string to the already existing string you use to click. This way you will write less code.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Ok that helps, yeah part of the problem is how long the code is when having so many options I'm trying to find as many ways to minimize how much i have to write.

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on your actual logic.
And I'm afraid this question might become flagged as it may be "too generic."

Still, there's a ton of ways to approach checking multiple states.

If you are expecting only a single result upon multiple checks (i.e. you would expect EITHER PersonalPolicy, FarmOwnersPolicy or SelectoMaticPolicy to be returned) personally i'd probably set a "PolicyType" variable and execute a switch-statement on it. Example:

```
switch(PolicyType){
    case "PersonalPolicy":
        // Code specific to PersonalPolicy
        break; // Don't forget to break unless you want to use "fallthrough logic"
    case "FarmOwnersPolicy":
       // Code specific to PersonalPolicy
       break ;
    case default:
       // Code for "any-other-than" cases :)
       break;
}
```

However for this approach to be feasible in your case, you'd have to have your separate bools resolved to some equivalent of an execution-level or error-level.

It is, however, also possible to link multiple conditionals to a larger single statement.
The most common-encountered examples are by using && or || between each statement to imply "AND" or "OR". Applying especially inverse-logic to OR-statements can prove to be powerful when comparing multiple bools

Example:

```
if ( PersonalPolicy ) { }
else { }

if (FarmOwnersPolicy && !SelectomaticPolicy ) {
    //Will only be executed if FarmOwnersPolicy is True AND SelectomaticPolicy is NOT true.
}

if (!FarmOwnersPolicy && !SelectomaticPolicy) {
    // Will only be executed if FarmOwnersPolicy AND SelectomaticPolicy are both unset
}

if (!FarmOwnersPolicy || !SelectomaticPolicy) {
    // Will  be executed if either FarmOwnersPolicy OR SelectomaticPolicy is unset
}
```

This latter approach may be more usefull when you have multiple conditions to be checked at once and to provide potential readability opposed to an endless streak of if-else's.

If I have "an (appearing to be) endless amount of checks", i usually try to break up each "set" of boolean-checks in blocks and a single resulting variable.

Its hard to give a good example for this, but Imagine we'd have a huuuuge form (for simplicity) where there's an address section, etc. I may want to check all address-info first, and compound that to an "AddressValid" bool, merely for improved readability in further sections :)
Also, if one part of that sequential bool-logic would break, it's potentially less hassle to read back into "what this code was doing" when you haven't touched that code in a bit.

Edit:

There's also the Conditional (Ternary) operator.
When used in the following example:

```
TestCase ? Value1 : Value2;
```

it results in the following logic:

```
If (TestCase ){
    return Value1;
}
Else {
    return Value2;
}
```

I use this "All the time" for setting default-values, or returning certain variables to default-values when it doesn't contain a value i'd expect.

Comment: This is helpful and seems to be what I'm looking for thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Also, concerning obtaining "default values" I've forgotten to mention one quite handy operator. The "Ternary Operator", I'll edit my answer to include this one in a few minutes :)